# Do I have to register my Chromecast device to develop an app that only uses the Default Media Receiver?

Tags: android, chromecast, android-developer-api

I'm working on an Android app that will simply play a video (from the web) on my Chromecast device. For this purpose I'm fine with just using the Default Media Receiver mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration), in which case I don't have to register my app to develop it. However, the app (in development) can't seem to find any of my Chromecast devices. On the page mentioned earlier, it did state (regarding the Chromecast device):

> To turn your device into a development device and gain access to your receiver app while it is not yet published, you must register the device.

This kind of makes it sound like I only have to register the Chromecast if I'm writing my own receiver app. Do I still need to register the Chromecast even if I'm just using the Default Media Receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to register your app if you want to use the Default Receiver.

Comment: I know. That's not my question though.

Comment: If you are using Default Receiver, you do not need to register anything. Does this answer your question?